# CSS Filter Blur 0 Affects Box-Shadow to Not Display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box that scales to 1.1x when hovered, but because the text becomes blurry, I used `filter: blur(0)` and that solved the issue (only to FireFox) . By using `filter: blur(0)` on the parent, the `box-shadow` property on the children elements stopped working.

I tried using a before and after pseudo-element but that didn't work either. Is there anything I can do to fix my issue?

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (e.style.transform === "rotateY(180deg)") e.style.transform = "rotateY(0)";
  else e.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
}
```

```css
body{background:mistyrose; padding: 50px;}
.r_card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  perspective: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
  filter: blur(0);
}
  .r_card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

.r_card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-header h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-header p {
  margin: 13px 0;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-description {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-description p {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.r_card:hover .r_card-inner {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px -3px black;
}

.r_card-front,
.r_card-back {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px 30px 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #E66343;
}

.r_card-front {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.r_card-front .r_card-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.r_card-front .r_card-links a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #E66343;
}

.r_card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.r_card3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr)/auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_card">
  <div class="r_card-inner" onclick="myFunction(this)" style="transform: rotateY(0deg);">
    <div class="r_card-front r_card3">
      <div class="r_card-header">
        <h3>Standard</h3>
        <p>Standard</p>
      </div>
      <div class="r_card-image"><img src="#">></div>
      <div class="r_card-description">
        <p>P Tag</p>
        <div class="r_card-links">
          <a href="#">More Info</a><br>
          <a href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="r_card-back">
      <h1>Peter</h1>
      <p>Art.</p>
      <p>Ext</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Weirdly enough, the code is not the same as what I have but the code is similar. From this result, they are issues I faced while modifying the card like the position of the card when flipping, the text still being blurry, and the drop shadow not appearing.

Thank you.

Chavez

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
filter: drop-shadow(1px 10px 4px #696982);
```

to your card. This way you can have both the blur and the shadow around your element.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (e.style.transform === "rotateY(180deg)") e.style.transform = "rotateY(0)";
  else e.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
}
```

```css
body{background:mistyrose; padding: 50px;}
.r_card {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  perspective: 500px;
  transition: transform 0.25s;
  filter: blur(0);
}
  .r_card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

.r_card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-header h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-header p {
  margin: 13px 0;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-description {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.r_card-inner .r_card-description p {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.r_card:hover .r_card-inner {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px -3px black;
}

.r_card-front,
.r_card-back {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 10px 30px 30px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #E66343;
}

.r_card-front {
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 10px 4px #696982);
}

.r_card-front .r_card-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.r_card-front .r_card-links a {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #E66343;
}

.r_card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.r_card3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr)/auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_card">
  <div class="r_card-inner" onclick="myFunction(this)" style="transform: rotateY(0deg);">
    <div class="r_card-front r_card3">
      <div class="r_card-header">
        <h3>Standard</h3>
        <p>Standard</p>
      </div>
      <div class="r_card-image"><img src="#">></div>
      <div class="r_card-description">
        <p>P Tag</p>
        <div class="r_card-links">
          <a href="#">More Info</a><br>
          <a href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="r_card-back">
      <h1>Peter</h1>
      <p>Art.</p>
      <p>Ext</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```